# Can a character craft and use doses of disease in the same manner as an alchemical item or poison?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, disease

I'm looking to make a character (well... villain) who deliberately and stealthily infects people with diseases, perhaps by tainting the local water, or food supply, then charges them for the cure.  I've already considered the Alchemist's Plague bomb, but it's too unsubtle.

The spell Full Pouch makes reference to a 'dose of disease'.  Are there rules in the system for crafting a dose in the same way as poison?

Answer (score 2):

Rogues have the [Disease Use](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/disease-use/) talent, which allows them to inflict the Filth Fever disease on targets. He simply has to collect some filth somewhere and apply to his weapons.

A 3rd level [antipaladin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/antipaladin/#TOC-Plague-Bringer-Ex-) is immune to the effects of diseases, but not immune to being afflicted by disease, which means he is a carrier who will never show signs of being disease (not without spells, at least). So, he could obtain this disease from normal means, and spread it around to others, while charging to cast Remove Disease obtained from another class (inquisitor, cleric, witch, etc).

Any class with access to the [Contagion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contagion/) spell can inflict one of the following diseases to touched creatures: blinding sickness, bubonic plague, cackle fever, filth fever, leprosy, mindfire, red ache, shakes, or slimy doom. Of course, there are stronger alternatives aswell: [Epidemic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/epidemic/) and [Plague Storm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plague-storm/).

As an alternative, you have the system of [crafting Drugs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/drugs/) from the [Alchemy Manual Player Companion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy90bj), which can be made using [Craft(Alchemy)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft). Those are [canon in Golarion](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Recreational_drugs_of_Golarion), the book even introduces a few drugs from [Katapesh](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Katapesh).

As for mundane ways of producing a disease, you would require something like [Profession](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/profession/) (Pharmaceutical Scientist), which doesn't seem to fit most medieval settings. But i could see it working with biologist aswell.